# Powershell logon script remove item

Tags: powershell, active-directory, gpo

I have a logon script that does the following:

```
$user = $env:username
remove-item -path c:\users\$user\appdata\local\FOLDER -recurse
```

It gets the username and removes a specific folder in the appdata of the user.

If I run this in the session of the user (*without elevated rights*) using `powershell` , it works.
However, if I run it via login script, it doesn't work. The script itself runs since other code ran correctly.

What am i doing  wrong?

Comment: Are you running the code in the login script as a different user perhaps? As an aside, you could also use `Join-Path -Path $env:LOCALAPPDATA -ChildPath 'FOLDER'` to build the path for the folder to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -Force switch if it helps.

```
$user = $env:username
remove-item -path c:\users\$user\appdata\local\FOLDER -recurse -Force
```